# useState returning to initial State

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently using useState to my Form. And in my form I have different function that I used in my inputs. Each type of input have different functions. Here are my functions

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('change');
  }, [MAINOBJECT]);

  const handleMainBasicChange = (e, resultsEnabled = 0) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target ? e.target : e;
    setMAINOBJECT(object => {
      return {
        ...object,
        [name]: resultsEnabled
          ? {
              results: value
            }
          : value
      };
    });
  };

  const handleCalendarChange = (name, value) => {
    setMAINOBJECT(object => {
      const nameField = value
        ? moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T08:00:00Z]')
        : null;
      return {
        ...object,
        [name]: nameField
      };
    });
  };

  const handleEventPeoplePickerChange = (name, valueArg, multiple = 0) => {
    console.log(MAINOBJECT);
    // let realValue;
    // if (multiple) {
    //   realValue = valueArg ? valueArg : [];
    //   targetObject[name] = { results: realValue };
    // } else {
    //   realValue = valueArg ? valueArg : 0;
    //   targetObject[name] = realValue;
    // }
    // setMAINOBJECT(targetObject);
  };
```

And here is my useState

```
const [MAINOBJECT, setMAINOBJECT] = useState(INITIALSTATE.IpetMainObject);
```

Now my problem is, I have no problem setting my state using "setMAINOBJECT" but when I try to use the function "handleEventPeoplePickerChange" after doing some changes using other the two other functions, somehow the MAINOBJECT is resetting back to its initial state that shows in the console.

After doing console.log in my handleEventPeoplePickerChange this is the value that showed. MAINOBJECT has value on Title and Status before I tried doing the console.log inside that cursed function

[image]

Comment: I tried using useEffect to see if there is someone changing "MAINOBJECT" that I missed but somehow nobody else is changing my MAINOBJECT state

Comment: Can you provide a CodeSandbox with your code (make it as simple as possible)?

Comment: Where is this coming from: `INITIALSTATE.IpetMainObject`

Comment: INITIALSTATE.IpetMainObjec is just a constant object

Comment: The weird thing is I added a useEffect inside the component that I used the "handleEventPeoplePickerChange " but it seems that before the value enter that component the value already reset to its initial state which is super crazy

Comment: Make a CodeSandbox showing your problem

Comment: That might be impossible because the component that uses handleEventPeoplePickerChange uses a SharePoint Library. I wont be able to render/show that component without SharePoint.

Comment: Remove it or mock it somehow. It will be one less suspect for your problem.

Comment: I already figure it out, somehow the useEffect inside my component is affecting and turning back my state into its default value. Not sure why, I am not even sharing my entire object in that component

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying object from state and then modifying it in place, try using the functional form of `setState`:

```
const handleMainBasicChange = (e, resultsEnabled = 0) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target ? e.target : e;

  setMAINOBJECT(object => {
    return {
      ...object,
      [name]: resultsEnabled ? {
        results: value
      } : value
    }
  });
};

const handleCalendarChange = (name, value) => {
  setMAINOBJECT(object => {
    const nameField = value ? moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T08:00:00Z]') : null
    return {
      ...object,
      [name]: nameField
    }
  });
};
```

Doing `let targetObject = { ...MAINOBJECT };` will only create shallow copy of the object, so you still might be mutating the state directly.

Comment: I tried changing they way I change value inside my object but its still going back to the initial value when I tried calling the function handleEventPeoplePickerChange.

Comment: Where and how do you call that function? It might be that console.log still shows the old value of the state.

Comment: I am calling them onChange in my input. Not sure because in my input I am using the property of my MAINOBJECT  as a value.  As soon as I call "handleEventPeoplePickerChange", all the key values return to null. I also check the developer toolbar and I can see my state got returned to its Initial Value which is weird

Comment: Can you add the full code for `handleEventPeoplePickerChange` to the question?

Comment: My previous code I commented out but when I do console.log inside it, it display the initial value of it

Comment: It seems the before I call the function somehow its getting return to its previous state. Because I tried using this and nobody was changing the MainObject after I call my peoplepickerchange function. Here is my useEffect that checks the changes

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('change');
  }, [MAINOBJECT]);

Comment: Try replacing `let targetObject = { ...MAINOBJECT };` everywhere with `setMAINOBJECT` function call.

Comment: I tried replacing my code on what you suggested but still the same.